# Regex disjunction in Python findall does not match full substrings

Tags: python, regex

In several online testers, the regex `a(b|c)z` matches both 'abz' and 'acz' in the string 'abz acz', but Python's re.findall() only matches 'b' and 'c'.

What am I missing?

```
In[42]: re.findall(r'a(b|c)z', 'abz acz')
Out[42]: ['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because you are using capturing parens

```
re.findall(r'a(?:b|c)z', 'abz acz')
```

`?:` will cause it to be non-capturing parentheses

Comment: Thanks, for me this answer addresses the root problem: I was not aware of the distinction between capturing and non-capturing parentheses. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Answer (score 3):

With `findall`, the captured groups are returned:

As stated in the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) ...

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

You can simply use a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) here instead.

```
>>> re.findall(r'a[bc]z', 'abz acz')
['abz', 'acz']
```